# php 5.6 elasticache client on alpine 3.4

Tags: php, docker, memcached, amazon-elasticache, alpine-linux

I'm building my image using php:5.6.30-fpm-alpine.  I pulled down the Elasticache php 5.6 client from AWS Console.

The exact error I'm seeing:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so'
>   - Error relocating /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so:
>   backtrace: symbol not found in Unknown on line 0

Any ideas on getting this to work?